# botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region for EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, airflow, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I am trying to create a emr-serverless application through the EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator but I keep facing the error botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

I am passing the region like below:

```
 create_app = EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator(
        task_id="create_spark_app",
        job_type="SPARK",
        release_label="emr-6.6.0",
        config={"aws_access_key_id":args["aws_access_key_id"], 
                "aws_secret_access_key": args["aws_secret_access_key"], 
                "aws_session_token": args["aws_session_token"],
                "region_name":'us-east-1'}
    )
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I passed them as environment variables.

```
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]= YOUR VALUE
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]= YOUR VALUE
os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"]= YOUR VALUE
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"]= YOUR VALUE
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the `region_name` attribute as part of `config` argument to `EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator`. Have you considered specifying the region with AWS connection instead? When the connection ID isn't specified with operator, it should default to `aws_default`.
Refer to this for more context. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html#default-connection-ids